# How to redirect to another controller when we are in OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filterattribute

Excuse my English is not good ,But I'm trying to get better. 
OK NOW
I have a content/Index action and view. and i have a form for submit comment with addcomment/Comment partial and partialview page. Now i uses from a filter for check insert time by user . any user allow insert comment in one minute . Now , if user insert first comment , i save one minute in cache in OnActionExecuted method and if again this user insert another comment , i check in cache for that user cache time Less than One Minute or No.
if less than One minute i Want redirect User in ErrorController/IndexAction ...
but in not work in Child Action . For Example Because Commnet/AddComment Action call in Content/Index Page... i think this method is child action and not redirect in Error controller. 
but i when use this filter in Content/Index .. that is can redirect to Error Controller. 
My Filter :

```
 public class ValidateSpamFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public bool IsAddress { get; set; }
    private string SecurityKey { get; set; }
    public ValidateSpamFilterAttribute(int duration, bool isAddress)
    {
        Duration = duration;
        IsAddress = isAddress;

    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        SecurityKey = CreateKey();
        var objReadCache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;
        if (objReadCache.Get(SecurityKey) != null)
        {

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", area = "", Exception = "بازه زمانی ثبت شما رعایت نشده است", ErrorCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Handler = "Controller" }
                    )
                    );
            filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext);


            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        }

    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        SecurityKey = CreateKey();
        var SecurityValue = SecurityKey;
        var SecurityTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Duration);
        var SecurityExp = System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration;
        var SecurityPri = System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal;
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(SecurityKey, SecurityValue, null, SecurityTime, SecurityExp, SecurityPri, null);
         base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
    private string CreateKey()
    {
        var IP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        var Info = (this.IsAddress) ? (HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl + HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString) : "";
        var UniqueString = String.Concat(IP, Info);
        var SecurityValue = string.Join("", System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create().ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(UniqueString)).Select(s => s.ToString("x2")));

        return SecurityValue;
    }


}
```

and first i call parent controller .Content/Index

```
      public ActionResult Index(int id, string title)
    {
        //anything
    }
```

and load my IndexPage. Now i load comment/addcomment action.

```
 [ValidateSpamFilter(duration: 10, isAddress: true)]
    // HttpPost Method For Submit Form . you can add comment by this method .
    public ActionResult AddComment(CommentAddDTO Comments)
    {
      //addcomment ....
    }
```

anyway my this code

```
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", area = "", Exception = "بازه زمانی ثبت شما رعایت نشده است", ErrorCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Handler = "Controller" }
                )
                );
        filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext);
```

Not work for me and can not redirect to Error Controller when i use this filter in Child Action.

Answer (score 1):

I am using below code for redirecting to other controller onActionExecuting:

> filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("Default", new
>   System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Error" }, {
>   "action", "Index" } });

Hope this helps..

Comment: no different between My redirect code with your code. both code are work fine . but my problem is this code just work a main action and not work a post action or partialviewresualt action.

Comment: This answer is very old, but Search Engines lead here. `filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult ... ...` is the way to got as described, but then add `return;` so that the current action won't continue.